# How can I add x-axis tick marks for each point using ggplot?

Tags: r

I am creating a graph looking at a concentration vs. date. My data is imported as day/month/year but when I graph the data, it is just using the year on the x axis. It is a pretty small data set and I would like each point to have a corresponding date.

Here is a little example of the data: 
Result  Date
24.8    25-Jul-18
22.8    08-Aug-18
24.8    22-Aug-18
26.3    06-Sep-18
27.6    18-Sep-18
29.9    03-Oct-18
29.5    04-Apr-19
25.9    15-Apr-19
28.3    02-May-19
28.3    15-May-19
27  31-May-19
26.3    12-Jun-19
25.5    26-Jun-19
24.9    10-Jul-19
25.4    06-Jul-16
24.7    20-Jul-16

```
ggplot(pipeline) + aes(pipeline$Date, pipeline$Result) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_line() +
  xlab("Year") + 
  ylab("Alkalinity mg/L")
```

I currently have a graph reflecting years but would like it broken down into the actual date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming the Date column in pipeline is not character.
    Hence simply turning Date column to character, should help with this.

```
#Code
pipeline$Date <- as.character(pipeline$Date)
ggplot(pipeline) + aes(pipeline$Date, pipeline$Result) +
geom_point() + 
geom_line() +
xlab("Year") + 
ylab("Alkalinity mg/L")
```